# How to create a Cipher wheel in Inkscape?

Tags: inkscape

How to create a Cipher Wheel as shown in picture with **Inkscape**?

I would like help to create these circles, then divide them in 36 equal parts. And write the letters in each pie as shown in picture.

[image: Cipher Wheel]

Comment: Hi. Welcome to GDSE. What specific problem are you having?

Comment: Updated my question

Comment: OK, I've added a brief answer to get you started. It's not a complete tutorial, just the basics.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Type one letter, set the text alignment to *centred*. Click twice on the text box to show rotation handles, and drag the rotation centre to the middle of the circle.  Use *Snapping to Object Rotation Centres* to get accuracy. Then duplicate and do a rotate transform, and repeat around the circle centre. Note that 10 degree angle increments will give you 36 characters around the circle.

[image]

Then you can apply the same duplicate and transform to radial lines

[image]

Finally, using the Text tool, double click in each text field to edit and retype the letters/nubmers as required. Repeat the process for the placement of other letters/numbers on different rows.

[image]

Comment: Thank you so much. It worked just fine. Previously I used to write the letters and attach to circle path and always had them cross some lines at some place or the other.

Answer (score 1):

I'd use the dialog for arranging objects on a circle.

So, the procedure would be to:

- type each letter as a single one-letter text, or type them into a long text and use an extension (Extensions > Text > Split... Letters) to split them up
- select all of them, in the correct order
- open Object > Arrange > Polar coordinates (or in Inkscape 1.2: Object > Arrange and Distribute > Circular)
- select a circle and choose the settings you want (reference point bottom center, rotate objects)
- apply

Video (1min 42s, taking time for extra demoing, a gif was still too large for SE):

https://peertube.linuxrocks.online/w/i21PyJdzb3CHMFXAPSQ1i8